# Applications unresponsive after Upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, upgrade, google-chrome, docky

I recently upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04. i386 running as 32-bit even though it is 64-bit in windows 7 (problem?).

The Upgrade 14.04 auto update dumped grub loader. I remedied that.

Once loaded and logged in, the system is normal. However many applications fail to load even though they appear to have loaded in sidebar.

Example: I click on chrome and an arrow appears next to it in side bar, but it will not come up. Affected apps:

- system monitor
- chrome
- xpad
- libreoffice
- docky

The mouse is also a little flaky and tends to be unresponsive from time to time or gets lost. I doubt it is related.

I got:

- 7.9 GB RAM
- Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5400 @ 2.70GHz × 2
- Gallium 0.4 on AMD CAICOS

any help is appreciated

j

Comment: Can you open a Terminal and start libreoffice from there? Do see any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

After further trial and error... it turns out the graphics card was plugged into the TV.  Applications were 'hiding' in the TV but did not show on the monitor until the TV was either mirrored or unplugged.  Still have issues, but they seem to be in my head alone ; )